# How to get a piece of data's datatype?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, types

How can I get back the datatype of a particular piece of data?

For example, say I have a table `User` with `name:string`, `id:integer`, and `created_at:time`.

For any arbitrary user, `user.name.[method]` should return "string",
`user.id.[method]` should return "integer", and `user.created_at.[method]` should return "time".

I tried "type" and "datatype" but they are both undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `.class`?

```
user.name.class.to_s # => "String"
user.id.class.to_s # => "Integer"
```

Answer (score 1):

[`column_for_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-column_for_attribute) might be helpful in this context:

```
user.column_for_attribute(:name).type
#=> :string
```